# knitr, rmarkdown, pander: Minimal md -> html for <body> ...</body> only

Tags: php, html, rstudio, knitr

I have some .md /.Rmd files for a web site where the web designer created a PHP
framework in which all content pages get inserted with as if they were
just the content between `<body> .. </body>`.  How can I convert them
to minimal html using any of `knitr, rmarkdown and pander`?

Another consideration is that I would like  to be able to include inline
images, like

```
![banner](images/banner.png)
```

but have these simply replaced by an `img` tag, like

```
<img src="images/banner.png" alt="banner">
```

where the image is found relative to the html file, and not inserted into the html file directly.

A preferred solution would be use a YAML header something like

```
---
output:
  html_document:
     body_only         
---
```

Or, anything else that would make it easy to compile a collection of these
to html using R Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two [options](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html) are key to this problem: `output: html_fragment` to get a fragment instead of a full document and `self_contained: false` to  get referenced images instead of data-URIs.

````
---
output: 
  html_fragment:
    self_contained: false
---

Some text. *Important*.

```{r, echo = FALSE}
plot(1)
```

![Other Image](path/to/other/image.jpg)
````

Running `rmarkdown::render` on this RMD file gives:

```
<p>Some text. <em>Important</em>.</p>
<p><img src="frag_files/figure-html/unnamed-chunk-1-1.png" title="" alt="" width="672" /></p>
<p><img src="path/to/other/image.jpg" alt="Other Image" /></p>
```

Comment: Excellent!  I was unaware of `html_fragment`. Is there a complete list/guide to the elements in YAML headers for .md, .Rmw files anywhere?

Comment: You mean more complete than the [rmarkdown documentation](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/) I referenced in the answer? ;-)